# Pdf Viewer using mupdf library

Tags: android, mupdf, pdfrenderer

I have tried mupdf library to render my pdf ie. to have my own PDF VIewer, but when i try to form libmupdf.so file using Cygwin on my Windows system, getting errors and .so file not building.

plz guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download latest android NDK
2. Install CYGWIN
3. Download complete source code of MUPDF (with thirty part tool)
4. Download ANT build for windows
5. set all needed path (JAVA_HOME,ANT_HOME)
6. go to MuPDF directory
7. Run MAKE command
8. Then Import project in android from c:\mupdf\android
9. Run your android project.

Don't forget to keep at least one pdf in Downloads folder

also follow all the step given in mupdf

Comment: when i try to run make command it says "make is not internal or external command" did i miss some installation? or i am missing some enviromental variable

Comment: @umerk44 Check if you have make installed: make -v. If not, download it from cygwin installer.