# Open mupdf source in eclipse

Tags: android, mupdf

I know this question had been asked before and there are some tutorials about this question, but I've been struggling with this for days with no success, I don`t know much about how to use Cygwin or ANT. I would like just to run MuPDF from source code in eclipse, after that I will find out how to combine it with my project. 
Once I used OCR reader by this tutorial: http://kurup87.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-ocr-tutorial-image-to-text.html that was simple and understandable, there some similar and simple tutorial for MuPDF?

I have read every question and tutorial on StackOverflow and with no success, I just need simple tutorial for this.

Comment: see this steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10071012/1289716

Comment: I read this already, what step 7 (Run MAKE command) means? What MAKE, from where?

Comment: I think from the command line ) You should run this command inside your dir with sources. Here is also one tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project

Comment: In one of my attempts at learning the integration process (MuPDF in my app), I quickly found out that using Cygwin was quite cumbersome. After a lot of problems on the Cygwin front, I decided to grab a PC that was not in use and install a copy of Ubuntu. It did help speed up the process. Unfortunately (or fortunately ;-)) the project got canned. But if your are really keen on taking the integration to a logical end, I would suggest installing Linux as against working on Cygwin.