# Cant load Webview containing PDF documents, flash files converted into HTML5 android

Tags: android

im trying to display PDF files in webview. im trying to load PDF via HTML5.
here is my source code:

WebView webview;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient()); 
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/test.pdf");
    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    String databasePath = this.getApplicationContext()
            .getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
    settings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help will b greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Load PDF / PDF Viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468621/android-load-pdf-pdf-viewer)

Answer (score 1):

Webview does not support PDF in android.

You need to use google doc.

So you can't load PDF in webview from asset folder.

Either **put your pdf in server** or

**Use some library** to read pdf like [mupdf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10071012/1289716)

i have also faced this problem [see this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10299839/1289716)

or you can use Intent.**ACTION_VIEW**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(filepath, "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable plugins in your WebView object like

```
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

---

Possible duplicate of [Android - Load PDF / PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468621/android-load-pdf-pdf-viewer/4525717#4525717)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code::Refer [this](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-open-pdf-file-in-webview.html)

```
public class MyPdfViewActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView mWebView=new WebView(MyPdfViewActivity.this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/test.pdf");
    setContentView(mWebView);
  }
}
```

**Updated::**

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(new File("assets/www/test.pdf"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf"); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: tried but it simply displays blank white screen. not working.

Comment: @Agarwal Shankar check your answer first ,becuase webview cant support pdf file directly and we have to use google docs.but OP have pdf in asset folder?

Comment: @Agarwal. Thanks for your answer. Your r right. WebView doesnt support pdf files. but i dont want to use google docs , is there any other way using which i can display pdf files.as i dont want to rely on third party .