# error in integration of mupdf library

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

I am working on a project in which i have to deal with pdf view. I am trying to integrate mupdf library in my project but getting error as mentioned below. I have followed all steps mentioned in readme document. please help me to solve this error.

```
Compile thumb : mupdf <= mupdf.c

jni/mupdf.c:10:18: fatal error: fitz.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdf/mupdf.o] Error 1
```

My Android.mk file

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TOP_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

MUPDF_ROOT := $(call my-dir)

include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/Core.mk
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/ThirdParty.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(MUPDF_ROOT)/draw \
    $(MUPDF_ROOT)/fitz \
    $(MUPDF_ROOT)/mupdf
LOCAL_CFLAGS :=
LOCAL_MODULE    := mupdf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mupdf.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := mupdfcore mupdfthirdparty

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the fitz.h file somewhere?

Comment: yes its placed inside fitz folder of mupdf library.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 fitz.h?? If yes, than it creates ambiguity.

Comment: Do you have "$(MUPDF_ROOT)/fitz" in the include list of your your Android.mk file?

Comment: yes its there. please check my android.mk file i have uploaded in my question.

Comment: my MUPDF_ROOT is "..", not "$(call my-dir)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke **./scripts/build-native.sh** (for Windows use cygwin), then run `ndk-build`

Comment: how to do this. i m getting this while executing this $ ./scripts/build-native.sh
-bash: ./scripts/build-native.sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 6):

This is how i succeeded in MuPDF.

download ndk and extract.
download cygwin and extract.
download mupdf source and thirdparty files.

extract source and thirdpart extract file add to here.

go to project directory using cygwin.

open project in eclipse and
      add this to application.mk

```
      NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.4.3
```

make header file using this command in cygwin

```
javah -jni -classpath bin/classes/ -d jni/ com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFActivity
```

use cd .. and go back to MupdfSource extract directory and execute

```
    make
```

then error come .Use

```
make NOX11=yes
```

go to project directory (android folder) in cygwin and

```
ndk-build
```

thats all 
you get .so file

run the project.

Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Thank You so much..
Really very nice description..thnx again

Comment: How to make command: javah -jni -classpath bin/classes/ -d jni/ com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFActivity
a tryed run, but getting error:
Error: cannot access android.app.Activity
  class file for android.app.Activity not found

Answer (score 1):

You have to run **make** command using Cygwin.

Comment: Just go to android folder in mupdf you have downloaded, and read **README** file from there.

Comment: get this error when run make
cp thirdparty/openjpeg-1.5.0/libopenjpeg/../opj_config.h.in.user build/debug/opj_config.h
cp: cannot stat `thirdparty/openjpeg-1.5.0/libopenjpeg/../opj_config.h.in.user': No such file or directory
Makethird:51: recipe for target `build/debug/opj_config.h' failed
make: *** [build/debug/opj_config.h] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10071012/1289716) steps

also take care of steps of **readme** file

Answer (score 0):

Replace `MUPDF_ROOT := $(call my-dir)` by `MUPDF_ROOT := ..`