# MUPDF Android latest source ndk-build Error NDK 8

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, mupdf

i'm new in using NDK8 and i want to build MUPDF library for my PDF Viewer project, i followed MuPdf Reader integrate in project and also this ReadMe.txt and i encountered this errors:.

```
Terminal Ouput

Compile thumb  : mupdfthirdparty <= sfnt.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfthirdparty <= truetype.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfthirdparty <= type1.c
StaticLibrary  : libmupdfthirdparty.a
SharedLibrary  : libmupdf.so
./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(pdf_xref.o): In function `pdf_init_document':
/Users/durgaprasad/guna/mupdf/android/jni/../../pdf/pdf_xref.c:784: undefined     reference  to `pdf_new_js'
 /Users/durgaprasad/guna/mupdf/android/jni/../../pdf/pdf_xref.c:785: undefined reference to `pdf_js_load_document_level'
  ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(pdf_xref.o): In function `pdf_close_document':
   /Users/durgaprasad/guna/mupdf/android/jni/../../pdf/pdf_xref.c:815: undefined reference to `pdf_drop_js'
 ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(pdf_xref.o): In function `pdf_new_document':
/Users/durgaprasad/guna/mupdf/android/jni/../../pdf/pdf_xref.c:1298: undefined    reference     to `pdf_write_document'
./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(pdf_annot.o): In function `pdf_load_annots':
/Users/durgaprasad/guna/mupdf/android/jni/../../pdf/pdf_annot.c:371: undefined reference to `pdf_update_appearance'
/Users/durgaprasad/guna/mupdf/android/jni/../../pdf/pdf_annot.c:403: undefined reference to `pdf_field_type'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libmupdf.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Refer this ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159759/error-in-integration-of-mupdf-library/12279638#12279638

Answer (score 1):

Depending on when you took a copy of the source, it is possible that you have a copy which will not build on Android. It was noticed yesterday (6th September) that the addition of a new set of features had broken the Android build. Naturally this was promptly fixed.

I would suggest that you pull a new set of source from the [official Git repository](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=tree) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some of the source files, or a library. The one where `pdf_new_js`, `pdf_js_load_document_level` and other missing symbols are defined.

Answer (score 0):

The steps in the read me

> 11) //removed some part
>
> On windows (where you are using cygwin), or on linux/macos, this can
>   be as simple as **running 'make'** in the top level directory. Even if
>   the make process fails, it should get far enough to generate you the
>   required 'generated' directory, and you can continue through these
>   instructions.
>
> 12) Change into the android directory, and **edit local.properties**
>   into your favourite editor. Change the sdk path there as appropriate.
>   This should be the only bit of localisation you need to do.
>
> 13) **Change into the android directory** (note, the android
>   directory, NOT the android/jni directory!), and execute (in a Cygwin
>   window on Windows!):
>
> ```
>    ndk-build
> ```
>
> 14) Then execute:
>
> ```
>    ant debug
> ```

You are probably running ndk-build make sure you are in the right folder
mupdf_source/android

and you have performed step 11 which you have to run in mupdf_source folder , from logs I think some problem is with step 11 .

Trying running it again and after that run ndk-build

**Update:**

I am using r7 on Ubuntu , I was able compile it just by following the instructions ,

- make sure the environment is set . Cross check by building a sample application which has native code , Example : http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html
- make sure android/local.properties.sample  has been edited and renamed to android/local.properties

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply. Step 11 has no problem. On Step 12, I edited the local.properties and everything is fine. My problem is with ndk-build only.