# How to integrate mupdf library?

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

I try to build the library mupdf, using the following sequence
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12279638/680267

I can not run command:

```
javah -jni -classpath bin/classes/ -d jni/ com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFActivity

Error: cannot access android.app.Activity class file for
android.app.Activity not found
```

I tried to specify the path to the folder with the android-sdk:

```
'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/JDK7/bin/javah.exe' -jni -classpath /cygdrive/c/Android/platforms/android-8/android.jar;/cygdrive/c/Users/Alexey/Documents/GitHub/mupdf/android/bin/classes -d jni/ com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFActivit

Error: no classes specified
-bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/Alexey/Documents/GitHub/mupdf/android/bin/classes: a directory
```

How to run this command?

Comment: in your second command, you need a / at the end of the classpath

Comment: You can also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project/8587527#8587527 There I tried to explain how to make mupdf to work.